# Laravel : Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$isAdmin

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access to the admin page through the login page but I get an error :

```
ErrorException Undefined property
Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$isAdmin
```

app\Http\Middleware\Admin.php

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->isAdmin == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'you don\'t have admin access');
    }
```

app\Http\Kernel.php

```
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

app\Http\Providers\User.php

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'isAdmin'
    ];
```

database\migrations\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->date('birth')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->float('balance')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Could someone help me to figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: In your Middleware..  If.. .. auth() - >user() - >isAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Middleware should look like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->isAdmin == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'you don\'t have admin access');
     }
```

This is the actual/working middleware in one of my apps:

```
class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (($request->user()->profile->role !== 'admin')) {
            return redirect('home')->with('warning', 'Access denied! Contact admin.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your case: if (($request->user()->isAdmin == 1)) {

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem. But now I have another error in the same file : Trying to get property 'isAdmin' of non-object. Do you know where this could come from?

Comment: it doesn't work, it tells me the same error as before but with user now : Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

Comment: Is there an user registered in users table?

Comment: I have a test user in my seed where I gave 'isAdmin' => 1

Comment: just change  to this    if($request->user()->isAdmin == 1){   I won't leave until it works :)

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work, it shows the same error : Trying to get property 'isAdmin' of non-object.

Comment: I believe you must have a home page... where everybody can land after login. Then put the middleware on routes for administrative purpose. You must be logged in for the middleware to work.

Comment: This Middleware is processed before the request is processed. In your case the request is for login. App cannot know if you are an admin if you are not logged in before accessing the middleware. So... First login.... Then access a route with middware isAdmin.

Comment: I tried your solution and it shows the same error so I change the line by if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1) and it redirected me to the login page but when I log, it redirects me to the home page and not the admin page so it doesn't work

Comment: On your home page create a link to admin page Ex.: @if(auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1) <a href="{{route('admin.page')}}">Admin page</a> @endif             After login you will see that only admin can have that link and a simple user if accesses the link is redirected.

Comment: Ok so i put this : if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1)
                    <a href="{{route('admin.index')}}">Admin Page</a>
                    else 
                    <a href={{route('/home')}}></a>
                    endif in my home.blade.php, and when I log in, it redirects me to the default admin page and not my custom admin page,so I think it's just a route problem